# Why does WinApi let me work with wchar_t as char?

Tags: c, winapi

I am reading C.Petzold's book about Windows Programming, and trying to understand how Windows handles Unicode.

For example, I've found some implementations of `wcslen()` that look like this:

```
size_t wcslen(const wchar_t* start)
{
    const wchar_t* end = start;
    while (*end != L'\0')
        ++end;
    return end - start;
}
```

And I want to see what would happen if I'll treat `wchar_t` just as `char`, so I wrote this function:

```
size_t CDECL mywcslen(wchar_t * s)
{
  
  size_t len = 0 ; 

  while(s[len]){
    ++len ; 
  }
  
  return len ; 
  
}
```

Which works perfectly, for some reason. For example, if I convert the string `"Hello"` to UTF-16 bytes, I will get this array of bytes:

`0048 0065 006c 006c 006f`

So the function should break when it encounters the first `00`, but it does not. Why?

Comment: you in both cases work with `wchar_t`

Comment: You are not treating `wchar_t` as a `char`. You are treating it as a 0 terminated string which makes perfect sense.

Comment: The two snippets do the same thing. Why do you think they're different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so function should break when it'll encounter first 00, but it does not. Why

You are reading two bytes at a time in your loop. So you are reading

- `0x0048` in the 1<sup>st</sup> loop iteration,
- `0x0065` in the 2<sup>nd</sup> loop iteration,
- `0x006C` in the 3<sup>rd</sup> loop iteration,
- `0x006C` in the 4<sup>th</sup> loop iteration,
- `0x006F` in the 5<sup>th</sup> loop iteration,
- `0x0000` in the 6<sup>th</sup> loop iteration.

These values are all non-zero, until your program reaches the 6<sup>th</sup> loop iteration. Therefore, your loop does not terminate until the 6<sup>th</sup> loop iteration.

If you want to treat `wchar_t` as `char`, then you would have to rewrite your function like this:

```
size_t CDECL mywcslen(wchar_t * s)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    char *p = (char*)s;

    while ( p[len] ) {
        ++len ; 
    }
  
    return len ; 
}
```

This function will behave as intended in your question. It will return a length of `1` for the UTF-16 string `L"Hello"`, because it will first encounter the byte value `0x48` and then the byte value `0x00`, assuming that `wchar_t` is stored in [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order.